# Get image source from cdata xmlnode

Tags: xml, android, split

How to get image source from cdata xmlnode?

the xmlnode:

```
<description>&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.site.com/id/?id=41564&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.site.com//news/images/2010/03_march/imagestock/thumb/22.jpg&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;  more text comes here </description>
```

I'm trying to get the http://www.site.com//news/images/2010/03_march/imagestock/thumb/22.jpg out from the description node..

Comment: What is "that"? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to get and print the src atrr value, post my solution down.

Answer (score 1):

ok , this is work for me ..

```
static  String getImageFromFeed(String _HtmlString) {

    Pattern p=null;
    Matcher m= null;
    String sUrl ="";



    try {

         p= Pattern.compile("src='(.*?)'");
         m= p.matcher(_HtmlString);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        sUrl = e.toString();
    }

    if  (m.find())
         {
          sUrl=m.group(1);

         }

    return sUrl;
}
```